# Error when using props.history.replace("/dashboard") to redirect to dashboard page when clicking the login button

Tags: reactjs

Error message:

```
bundle.js:383 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at onLoginClick
```

My code:

```
props.history.replace("/dashboard");
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class YourComponent extends Component {
  redirectToPage = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/target-page'); // Redirect to the desired page
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Your Component</h1>
        <button onClick={this.redirectToPage}>Redirect to Page</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
        
function YourComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();
        
  const onLoginClick = () => {
    history.replace("/dashboard");
  }
        
  // Your component's rendering logic
}
```

else you can try useNavigate hook

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
        
function YourComponent() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
        
  const onLoginClick = () => {
    navigate('/dashboard');
  }

  // Your component's rendering logic
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough information so questioner can better understand.